# Adding paint code to trackbar control

Tags: c#

I want to add text labels onder the tick marks of a trackbar control. Initially everything appears fine but when a drag the thumb of the trackbar my text labels disappear. What is happening here ?

Here is my code :

```
public class DateTimeTrackBar : TrackBar
{
    public DateTimeTrackBar()
    {
        :
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
    }
    :
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {     
        base.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, false);

        base.Refresh();

        if (ShowLabels)
            DrawLabels(e);

        base.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);

        //base.OnPaint(e);
    }

    protected virtual void DrawLabels(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        int nNumTicks = GetNumTicks(this);

        if (nNumTicks > 0)
        {
            PointF[] TickLocs = GetTickLocations(nNumTicks);
            string[] TickLabels = GetTickLabels(nNumTicks);

            using (Font ArialFnt = new Font("Arial", 6, FontStyle.Regular))
            {
                using (Brush GrayBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Gray))
                {
                    float fTickLabelLocOffset;

                    for (int i = 0; i < nNumTicks; i++)
                    {
                        if (!ShowMinMaxLabels && ((i == 0) || (i == (nNumTicks - 1))))
                            continue;

                        if (i == 0)
                            fTickLabelLocOffset = 0.0f;
                        else
                        {
                            SizeF Size = e.Graphics.MeasureString(TickLabels[i], ArialFnt);

                            if (i == (nNumTicks - 1))
                                fTickLabelLocOffset = Size.Width;
                            else
                                fTickLabelLocOffset = (Size.Width / 2.0f);
                        }

                        PointF TickLabelLoc = new PointF(TickLocs[i].X - fTickLabelLocOffset, TickLocs[i].Y + 8);

                        e.Graphics.DrawString(TickLabels[i], ArialFnt, GrayBrush, TickLabelLoc);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    :
}
```

Comment: This snippet is not very helpful.  Try overriding OnPaintBackground() instead.

Answer (score 0):

The standard convention here would be to not set the `UserPaint` style, to call `base.OnPaint()` in your override method, and then render your custom graphics after the call to `base.OnPaint()` returns, similar to this:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{     
    base.OnPaint(e);

    if (ShowLabels)
        DrawLabels(e);
}
```

---

Based on the documentation for `Control.SetStyle()` at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.setstyle(v=vs.110).aspx as well as the `ControlStyles` enumeration at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlstyles(v=vs.110).aspx, consider the following:

- You should not be calling `SetStyle()` repeatedly to change the flags (as happens in your `OnPaint()` method).  These should be set once, when the control is initialized.
- When you set the `UserPaint` flag to true, you are telling Windows the following.  This is likely not your intent:

> If true, the control paints itself rather than the operating system
>   doing so. If false, the Paint event is not raised. This style only
>   applies to classes derived from Control.

Comment: When I use the UserPaint style and the code you use above, only the labels are drawn. There is no Trackbar.

Comment: @Ron You write in your comment "When I use the UserPaint style" but my suggestion is that you should NOT use the UserPaint style.